# No refactorings available on Apex Classes when using VS Code

Tags: apex, ide, visualstudiocode

I used to be able to refactor/extract methods from VS code as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/refactoring/)

Now whenever I try to do this, I get an error saying

> No refactorings available

[image]

I tried uninstalling and installing again the Salesforce apex extension pack but that didn't make a difference.

Thoughts?

Comment: What type of files did you do this before on? I don't believe you can extract a method in apex (as the documentation only goes over extracting a constant and renaming symbols). You can extract methods and use "refactor" on LWC/js as it's supported in VS code.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I was 100% able to do it with methods in Apex, even though the docs don't state it.

Comment: I get the same message you get when trying on apex. It works fine on JS within LWCs though.